# Azure SQL DW - Control Resource Class on Query Level

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-sql-server

I am running some ETL on my Azure SQL DW at DW500
so I have 20 concurrency slots available
some of my queries would require RC xlargerc, some largerc, etc
so the expected load can vary from query to query

is there any option to control the assigned RC in the query directly?
e.g. using OPTION or any other hints?

the only workaround I could find so far is to create separate users with different resource classes assigned which is not really feasible

thanks in advance,
-gerhard

Comment: You could vote for https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/14602701-resource-class-override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no option to control this at query level.  You have to be logged in as the appropriate user with the appropriate resource class (smallrc, mediumrc, largerc, and xlargerc) assigned to them.

DWU500 is pretty low, with max 20 concurrent queries and only 20 concurrency slots.  Remember an xlargerc user would take 16 of those slots, as per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-concurrency), so you could only have 1 other mediumrc user or 4 smallrc users running at the same time.  ie you could **not** have one largerc and one xlargerc user running at the same time.   These queries would queue.

Can you tell us a bit more about your scenario?  For example, why switch users during ETL?  What ETL tool are you using, eg SSIS, Azure Data Factory etc

If you think this is a worthwhile option, consider making a [feedback request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse).

Comment: yes, that's exactly the issue I ran into, thinking that using a large RC would speed up my ETL
I just reread the documentation and it is also stated there so i guess i have to go with multiple user for my ETL then

thanks, -gerhard

Comment: You could consider ramping up the DWU for the period of the ETL then reducing again?  This only really matters if you are doing things in parallel and/or require concurrency.  Is this the case?

Comment: increasing the DWU does only partially solve the problem as even for higher DWUs with more concurrency slots, also xlargerc queries are assigned more concurrency slots hence having only minimal impact on the amount of parallel queries.

for now i reduced the resource class of my user to mediumrc which at least allows 5 concurrent sessions.

Comment: also added a comment to the Feedback-item at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/14602701-resource-class-override#comments with my requests/ideas

Comment: Well yes but it's a sliding scale.  At DWU500 you are in the middle of a band of 3 (DWU400,500,600) where an xlargerc uses 16 concurrency slots, so you could only have 1 other mediumrc user or 4 smallrc users running at the same time.  At DWU600, so you could have either 1 other largerc user, or 2 mediumrc users or 8 smallrc users, so you could increase concurrency by raising DWU by 100, for example.